# Use conda env with exec (www-data user)

Tags: php, debian, conda

Is there a possibility of using a conda env when executing a command via exec or shell_exec ? For instance such as :

```
shell_exec("python test.py");
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out one solution will be of directly using the python3 executable from the conda env files.

In my case :

```
/root/anaconda3/envs/<ENV_NAME_HERE>/bin/python3
```